# C programming - asterisk-shape

Tags: c

Hi I want to print shapes like this with *.
The height of this shape is 6 and if entering another even integer as height, it will produce  a shape with that height.

[image]

So far I am doing this, but this failed.....
Would anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int height;
    int i, j;

    printf("Please input height with an even integer ");
    scanf("%d", &height);

    for (i=height/2; i>=1; i--)
    {

        for (j=1; j<=height; j++)
        {
            if (i==height/2)
                printf("*");
            else if (j=i || j==(height-(i-1)))
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Thanks everyone!

Actually I tried another method earlier and it worked out.

I printed out the top line and the bottom line first and put asterisks and space to where it should be.

Here is my solution.

```
void printStar(int x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int height, value = 2 , value2;

        printf("Please input height with an even integer ");
        scanf("%d", &height);

        value2 = height-1;

        for (int i=1; i<=height; i++)
        {

         if(i==1){

               printStar(height);

         }else if(i == height){

               printStar(height);

         }else{

               for(int y = 1 ; y<=height ; y++){

                    if(value == y || value2 == y){

                         printf("*");           

                    }else{

                         printf(" ");   

                    }

               }
                value++;
                value2--;       

         }  
         printf("\n");
        } 


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void printStar(int x){
     for(int i = 0 ; i<x ;i++){
          printf("*");  
     }

}
```

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Or use a debugger to step through the code line by line.

Comment: `else if (j=i || j==(height-(i-1)))` you mean `j==i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is deviced so you think logically about the problem. Divide the problem into different parts, upper part and lower part (the divide and conquer technique), *then* solve the problem. It is not constructive to ask others to solve your problem. Here is the solution to your problem at the moment, but remember why your homework was to solve this in the first place.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int height = 1;
  int i, j;
  while((height % 2 != 0) && height > 0){
    printf("Enter Height: ");
    scanf("%d",&height);
  }
  /*first half*/
  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) putchar('*');printf("\n");
  for(i = 1; i < height/2; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      if(j == i || j == (height-i-1))putchar('*'); else putchar(' ');
    } printf("\n");
  }
  /*second half*/
  for(i = height/2 -1; i > 0; i--){
    for(j = 0; j < height; j++){
      if(j == i || j == (height - i - 1))putchar('*'); else putchar(' ');
    } printf("\n");
  }
  for(i = 0; i < height; i++) putchar('*');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
Although I finally finished this program, I didn't work through this idea :(

Answer (score 0):

I think in the `if (j=i || j==(height-(i-1)))` the `j=i` is wrong.

Comment: Indeed, this is wrong. But this doesn't solve his problem. The program will output a wrong shape.

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to change:

- `for (i=height/2; i>=1; i--)` should be `for (i=height; i>=1; i--)`
- `if (i==height/2)` should be `if (i==height || i==1)`
- `else if (j=i || j==(height-(i-1)))` should be `else if (j==i || j==(height-(i-1)))`

After these changes, for `height==6` your program will output:

```
******
 *  * 
  **  
  **  
 *  * 
******
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=height; i>=1; i--)
{
    for (j=1; j<=height; j++)
    {
        if (i==height || i==1)
            printf("*");
        else if (j==i || j==(height-(i-1)))
            printf("*");
        else
            printf(" ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```